# Очистка поля ввода при клике на него

Tags: javascript

Задача проста. На сайте есть форма обратной связи. По умолчанию поля текста содержат некоторые значения. Как сделать так, чтобы при клике на поле первоначальный текст пропадал и пользователь мог ввести свою инфу?
Пробую вот так, не получается почему-то:

```
<td onclick='document.getElementById('name').value="";'>{name:body}</td>
```

`{name:body}` - это вставка самого `input` в форму. `ID=name` у `INPUT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть простой вариант, это добавляется к текстовому полю:

```
onblur="javascript:if(this.value==''){this.value='Enter Search keywords'};" onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter Search keywords') {this.value='';}" value="Enter Search keywords"
```

Но я рекомендую более красивый здесь http://gword.ru/(поля в форме Оставить заявку). Через firebug легко понять как работает, если нужно могу выложить код

Comment: проблема в том что я могу прописать событие только  для ячейки таблицы в которой размещается само текстовое поле... может вы мне поясните почему не работает мой вариант?

Comment: Кавычки, думаю, так должно работать:

    <td onclick="document.getElementById('name').value=\'\';">{name:body}</td>

Answer (score 4):

Изначально у Вас все было верно, только единственное что нужно было поменять это кавычки ' ' в `getElementById` на " ", скрипт видел здесь одинарную кавычку как закрытие онклика.
Надо было так:

```
onclick='document.getElementById("name").value="";'
```

Answer (score 2):

Такими методами мой прапрадедушка верстал. Сейчас делают проще:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Поиск" value="" />
```

И любой polyfill для старых браузеров из раздела «[Web Forms : input placeholder](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills)», например [Enhanced jQuery Placeholder plugin](https://github.com/dciccale/placeholder-enhanced).

**Update:** Если до `<input>` никак не добраться (шаблонизатор мешает и т.п.), то можно всегда сказать что-то в духе

```
<script>
    $("input[name='search']").prop("placeholder", "Поиск"); // Или .attr, не соображу с ходу, а проверять лень.
</script>
```

Заодно не будет мешать браузерам без JavaScript.

Comment: Какое это имеет отношение к верстке?О_о

Comment: А HTML это что — программирование, что ли?

Comment: какое отношение имеет javascript к html?

Comment: Ну, вопрос-то не про JS, а про поле ввода (`<input>`, т.е. про HTML). А чем оно делается — дело десятое.

Да и атрибуты `onblur`/`onfocus` — верстка в чистом виде (и, по трендам — не пишут сейчас их, предпочитают навешивать обработчики по-другому, не мешая представление с логикой). Программирование — это внутри.